# Get cordinates of text read from image - ocrad.js

Tags: javascript, html, ocr

I'm capturing an image using webcam and trying to read the text on it. Now it reads all the text. I want to filter only letters and numbers from the image. And also want to get the coordinates of text. To get the coordinates I have followed this [link](https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js/blob/master/examples/browser/location.html). But it's not working. No other references for this solution was not found.

```
 <script src="ocrad.js"></script>
 <script>
  // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');
 // Get access to the camera!
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
// Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.play();
});
}
// Elements for taking the snapshot
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Trigger photo take
document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById('transcription').innerText = "(Recognizing...)";
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);

OCRAD( canvas, function(text){
                document.getElementById('transcription').className = "done"
                document.getElementById('transcription').innerText = text;
            })
    });
 </script>
```